# gVim not recognizing all installed fonts

Tags: fonts, vim

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu and installed vim and gVim using `sudo apt install vim-gtk3` and also installed "Fixedsys Excelsior" font via font manager. On my previous installation the font worked fine.

Now when I open the font selector in gVim I can see other fonts but not this one.

I would also like to point out that if I try to use the font in Geany it works, so perhaps it has to do with the vim version I installed?

Also if I check the font-manager it shows me that the Fixedsys font is installed only at "User" not also at "System".

What I tried so far:

- Installed the font manulay
- Installed the font from different sources
- Restarted the computer
- Catched the fonts
- Installed microsoft fonts